# Node unable to verify the first certificate when accessing CouchDB through HTTPS with a Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate, couchdb, lets-encrypt

I actually found the answer to this question already, and just want to document my finding.

The problem has to do with using **Node.js** to access **CouchDB** through *HTTPS*. The **CouchDB** server has been configured with a *SSL* certificate generated by **Let's Encrypt**. The **cert_file** specified in **local.ini** contains both the server certificate and the issue's intermediate certificate. When I verified an URL through the browser, the connection was shown as valid. However, whenever I tried to fetch the same URL from **Node**, an *UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE / unable to verify the first certificate* error would be thrown.

I tried adding the root certificate to **Node** using the **NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS** environment variable. That failed. Then, I tried adding the intermediate certificate to **NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS**, and it worked. I could stop there, but somehow I knew that something was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more digging, I finally found that even though the **cert_file** used by **CouchDB** includes both the server cert and the intermediate cert, unlike some other servers, **CouchDB** itself would only send back the server cert. In order to fix this problem the right way, I need to specify the intermediate cert as the **cacert_file** in the **local.ini** file as well. Once I did that, the error is gone.